# Heroku paypal_adaptive gem setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, paypal

I have paypal_adaptive gem on my local development machine working. But when deployed heroku throws me error that:

```
 ArgumentError: syntax error on line 20, col 2: `  ssl_cert_file:'
    /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
    /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/paypal_adaptive-a3853ca1635b/lib/paypal_adaptive/config.rb:32:in `load
```

I tried with and without line "ssl_cert_file:" in YML file and variables are saved to ENV variables to Heroku.  I suspect that gem can't find YML file. How to force gem to find that YML file.

Comment: Update: I creted payment request but when i send it to PayPal:
NoMethodError: undefined method strip' for 1322438087:Fixnum
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1304:inblock in initialize_http_header'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1302:in each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1302:ininitialize_http_header'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1670:in `initialize'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent a fix related to this that has been pulled in. http.rb can't handle non strings
See: https://github.com/tc/paypal_adaptive/commit/3e94637d56959994dc4c57186209f071fecc46bb

The gem just needs a version bump.